# my login button doesn't navigate to the next page

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to make  button that navigates to another page but when I click it nothing happens although the console doesn't show any errors if I click it
the login button should navigate to the LoginView component which is another page

here's the button:

```
<Button title="Login" style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton,styles.top]} onPress={() => navigationRef.current.navigate("Details")} >
 <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
```

and here I made expo snack for it:
https://snack.expo.io/@mai95/crabby-french-fries

and here's the App.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Image,TouchableHighlight,TextInput,
  Button, } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import logo from './assets/logo4.png'
import logo2 from './assets/CFA_approved_prep_provider_RGB.png'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import { Component } from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import  { useRef } from "react";


 class LoginView extends React.Component {
  


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email   : '',
      password: '',
      name:'',
      phone:'',
      fontsLoaded:false,
    }
  }
  async componentDidMount(){
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'comfortaa':require('./assets/fonts/Comfortaa/static/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({fontsLoaded:true})
  }
  

  render() {
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            { this.state.fontsLoaded && (<Text style={{fontFamily:'comfortaa',paddingBottom:40,
  marginLeft:30,
  fontSize:50}}>
      Register
      </Text>)}
      <View style={styles.Center}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Name"
              keyboardType="default"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}/>
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Phone"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(phone) => this.setState({phone})}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Email"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}/>
        </View>

              <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]} >
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight> 
        <Text style={styles.sign} >
      By signing up, you agree to finguru's <Text style={styles.underline}>Terms of service</Text> and <Text style={styles.underline}>Privacy Policy</Text>
      </Text>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  
  }


}
let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    
    backgroundColor:'white',
  },
  Center:{
  alignItems:'center'
  },
  inputContainer: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      width:300,
      height:45,
      marginBottom:20,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems:'center',
      borderColor:'black',
      borderWidth:3,
  },
sign: {
marginLeft:15,
lineHeight:18,
fontSize:15,
},
underline:{
  textDecorationLine:'underline',
},
  Register:{
  
  fontFamily:'Sans-serif',
  },
  inputs:{
      height:45,
      marginLeft:16,
      borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
      flex:1,
  },
  inputIcon:{
    width:30,
    height:30,
    marginLeft:15,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    height:45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom:20,
    width:300,
    borderRadius:6,
    
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#00b5ec",
  },
  loginText: {
    color: 'white',
  }
});
 
enableScreens();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

function Details({navigation}){
  return (
    <LoginView/>
   );
 }function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}
     >
       <Button buttonStyle="raised" title="Go To Details" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")} >
       </Button>  
     </View>
   );
 }
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';



    

export default function App() {
  const navigationRef = useRef(null)
  
  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
     <Image
        
        source={logo}
        style={styles.stretch}
      />
      <Image
        
        source={logo2}
        style={styles.stretch2}
      />
      
  
  <Button title="Login" style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton,styles.top]} onPress={() => navigationRef.current.navigate("Details")} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOG IN</Text>
   </Button>  
   <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer2, styles.loginButton2,styles.top2]} >
     <Text style={styles.loginText2}>Register</Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>  
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          
  <Stack.Navigator >
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
</NavigationContainer>
        </View>
    
  );
}



styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
  },
   stretch: {
    width: 175,
    height: 43.5,
    marginTop:170,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
  },
  stretch2: {
    width: 240,
    height: 31.9,
    marginTop:50,
    resizeMode:'stretch',
  },

  
  buttonContainer: {
    height:45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    
    width:130,
  
    
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#00b5ec",
    
  },
  loginText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  top:{
    marginTop:200,
  },
  buttonContainer2: {
    height:45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    
    width:130,
    
  },
  loginButton2: {
    backgroundColor: "#00b5ec",
    
  },
  loginText2: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  top2:{
    marginTop:200,
    marginLeft:20,
  },
  cont:{
    flexDirection:'row',

  },
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NavigationContainer` should be your top level component. Also it's defined after you define your button that uses the `navigationRef` to navigate to the `Details` screen.

I recommend you to create another stack screen for your `Login` screen and set this to be your initial route.

So the overall structure should look more like this:

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
     <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} /> // You need to create this component
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then you can put that login button somewhere in the `LoginScreen` component and its `onClick` using the `navigationRef` will work.

Comment: what components should be in the new stack screen?

Comment: I would put the non navigation related components that are currently inside the `App` component (The View, the Image components, the Button components, the TouchableHighlight component, the Text Component) in the new screen.